# Mathematicians who started out studying something else

Tags: soft-question, mathematicians

I did not know much about modern mathematicians's biographies. One of my friend has just told me Edward Witten was a history student when he was undergradute. 
Are there any different modern mathematicians who were not a mathematics(physics?) student, and then they changed their mind to be come a mathematician(physicist?)? We have already knew that Gauss was also interested in philosophy in the past, but he changed after proving the cosntrucible of Heptadecagon.

In fact, I did search for the appropriate tag for this question, but I only found history is good enough. If you are a moderator, please help me. This is also a soft question, so please give me some example before closing it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76580/famous-mathematicians-with-background-in-arts-humanities-law-etc-closed) has many examples of mathematicians who did this.